# Defining two separate API endpoints for essentially the same logic just for the sake of avoiding REST anti-patterns?

Tags: laravel, api, rest, web-architecture

Suppose we have a M:M relationship between a `User` model and a `Project` model in a project management SaaS. Naturally we have a pivot table mapping users to projects. An entry is deleted either if the user leaves or if the project manager removes that user from the project.

Even though the final result is essentially the same (i.e., the entry is deleted), I imagine it would be better to distinguish between these two actions by defining two separate API endpoints as follows:

**user leaves project**

route `DELETE /users/{id}/projects/{id}`

action `UserProjectController@destroy($id)` where `$id` refers to the project

**project manager removes user**

route `DELETE /projects/{id}/participants/{id}`

action `ProjectParticipantController@destroy($id)` where `$id` refers to the user

Should I ignore Cruddy by Design and RESTful design principles and simply define `leave()` `join()` `remove()` actions instead and use verbs in the URIs? like so:

`POST /projects/{id}/join`

`POST /projects/{id}/leave`

`POST /projects/{id}/participants/{id}/remove`

Answer (score 0):

`join`,`leave`,`remove` are arguably RPC rather than REST. Pivot tables etc are how the domain is implemented and are irrelevant to the caller of the API, which works at the domain level. How do the URLs map to your domain model?

If `Project` has one or more `User` why not just use

```
/projects/{id}/
```

to manage everything about `Project` and `Participant` instances?

`User` is in a `Project` but only if

```
/projects/{id}/participants/{id}
```

has been called.

FWIW,

```
DELETE /users/{id}/projects/{id}
```

looks like it's deleting the `Project` instance owned by a `User` as the `Project` object has `participants` but the `User` doesn't use that terminology. Perhaps it would be:

```
DELETE /users/{id}/projects/{id}/participants
```

for consistency with the domain model.

However it seems much easier to just use `Project` to manage `Project` instances. Removing a `User` from a `Project` using the `User` API seems a convenience that complicates the backend and doesn't really match the `Project` terminology. That would mean only having `UserController` and `ProjectController` classes.

You would have to consider whether a `Participant` `id` is the same as a `User` `id` and whether the pivot table handles that but that won't affect the API. The API should be an intuitive representation of your domain model.

Comment: You raised a good point vis-à-vis `DELETE /users/{id}/projects/{id}`. Perhaps it makes more sense to have a single API end point for 1. a user to leave a project and 2. a project manager removing a user from a project. One could simply add a Gate to the controller function checking that the request was sent from either the project manager or the user who is being removed.

Answer (score 0):

Something to consider: how would you do it on the web?

> Even though the final result is essentially the same (i.e., the entry is deleted), I imagine it would be better to distinguish between these two actions by defining two separate API endpoints

So on the web, you might well have two different *forms* that are used to "achieve the same result", but that doesn't necessarily mean that the forms should target different *resources*.

```
POST /foo
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

action=UnsubscribeUser&otherArguments=....
```

```
POST /foo
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

action=CancelProject&otherArguments=....
```

"One resource or two resources" isn't a question of right or wrong, but rather a question of trade-offs.

```
POST /projects/{id}/join
POST /projects/{id}/leave
POST /projects/{id}/participants/{id}/remove
```

That's also "fine"; again, it's a question of trade offs.  The machines don't care that your identifiers have a verb in the URI.

They do, somewhat, care whether or not the identifier for reading is the same as the identifier for writing.  See [RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4).

But it's perfectly reasonable to say that having semantically significant URI spellings in the access log or browser history are more important to our long term success than cache-invalidation.

---

Keep firmly in mind that DELETE - in the context of HTTP - does not mean the same thing as DELETE in the context of SQL; we're talking about two different name spaces with their own semantics.

HTTP [DELETE](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.5) is of the [transfer of documents over a network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s) domain.  The fact that the implementation of your handler includes a SQL DELETE is completely irrelevant.

> Relatively few resources allow the DELETE method -- its primary use is for remote authoring environments, where the user has some direction regarding its effect.

It is [OK to use POST](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post).